# Alternative Advertisers for my web site

Tags: advertising

I have a website where I have many of the programs I host, and I am looking for alternatives for publishing ads. The reason why I'm asking is because traffic on my site has more then tripled the ad revenue has gone down.

I know about [google adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense) and [adbrite](http://www.adbrite.com/).

Requirements are:

- Control over the ads
- Regular ads
- (bonus) Ability to control the ads via "type" like automaticly block moving/annoying clash ads

My site has over 20k pageviews a month.

### AdSense

- +No minimum requirements for traffic.
- +No adult ads
- +Some times gives out free ad money, so you can advertise you site.
- -Very limited control over the ads ( You can block specific domains where the ads come from).
- -Many "scammy" ads over products that seems to good to be true (IE download X to fix your computer).

### Adbrite

- -Can't really say much about them, I "gave" them 250k page views and I got less then 1 dollar in revenue back.

**When adding information about an ad publisher, please provide some basic information to help others viewing this topic. And if your willing provide personal experience also.**

Comment: It might help to know the subject matter of your site. Some ad providers are genre specific.

Comment: Not gonna add more information about my case, as its community wiki now. So hopefully make it so generic that others will enjoy the information provided to.

Answer (score 1):

[Commission Junction](http://www.cj.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Project Wonderful](http://www.projectwonderful.com/) is something used on [Schlock Mercenary](http://schlockmercenary.com/) and the I remember the owner, Howard Tayler, talking about similar control issues.

Answer (score 1):

What about [OpenX](http://www.openx.org/)?
They even got a hosted service.

Answer (score 0):

[Burst Media](http://www.burstmedia.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[ValueClick Media](http://www.valueclickmedia.com/)