# What affiliate network would you recommend and why?

Tags: advertising, affiliate

There are many ad and affiliate networks out there, that each try to cover a niche. Please list your favorites and give some reasons why you like them.

Comment: This should be community wiki because it is requesting peoples favorites.

Comment: What's an affiliate network?

Comment: An affiliate network manages relationships between publishers (content websites) and advertisers (people who want to advertise and sell product to the audience of those websites)

Comment: As of your explanation Google Adsense ia an affiliate program.

Comment: Adsense is a cost per click (CPC) program, not an affiliate program.

Comment: this is a dupe question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2026/1160

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RE: What is an affiliate network? Answer: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affiliate_network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affiliate_network)

1. [Commission Junction](http://cj.com)
2. [Linkshare.com](http://linkshare.com)
3. [Hydra Network](http://www.hydragroup.com/)
4. [Click Bank](http://www.clickbank.com/)
5. [Click Booth](http://www.clickbooth.com/)
6. [Click Speed](http://www.clickspeed.com/)

Comment: Thanks Dan! Do you have personal experience with these? Pros / cons?

Comment: It wouldn't be fare to really say, because I work for one of them :p

Comment: Google Affiliate Network which is a subset of Google Adsense. Easy to use from my experience with new publishers added weekly.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Amazon Affiliate Program](http://affiliate-program.amazon.com/) on one of my websites, and find their aStore (iframe shop in your website) especially interesting.

But in general, when you have a product that you are writing about -- try going to the company webpage and check if they have a link to their affiliate program at the bottom.

Most big companies use [CommissionJunction](http://www.cj.com/), some smaller ones use [Google Affiliate Network](http://google.com/affiliatenetwork/) ... but there are hundreds of those out there. The important bit is to read the terms of service and note what will you be getting from the clicks on the affiliate links.

Answer (score 0):

Adscluster: They have a wide range of publishers, tailored websites and blogs and they pay great comissions to affiliates.
Contextua: They have an innovative way of advertising via linking words.
Google Affiliate Network: Easy to use though comissions are poor.